# How does python change the value of input variable in a function even when it's assigned to another variable?

Tags: python, function, python-3.x

I want to define a function with **a list** x being its input variable, assume that I want to make the value of the input variable (x)  unchanged after performing the function, what I thought I should do is to assign the value of the input variable (x) to another variable (y) and do the calculations on this new variable (y) and return y at the end keeping the input variable x untouched (this is the second function in the code).

Implementing that code gives the same results as if I've not added a new variable y and performed the calculations on y. The value of x is changed. (It gives the same results as the first function)

I've found that assigning the value of x to y indirectly by constructing an empty list y and then adding entries of x one by one to y and then performing the operation on y solves the problem (as in the third function in the code).

My question is, why do python do that? Shouldn't it be the case that when I assigned the value of x to y and do calculations on y that x stay unchanged? what am I missing?

```
def li(X):
   X.append(1)
   return(X)

def le(X):
   Y=X
   Y.append(1)
   return(Y)

def lo(X):
   Y=[]
   for i in range(X):
          Y.append(X[i])
   Y.append(1)
   return(X)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> what am I missing?

You're problem lies in the way Python's variables work. You see, when you assign the list `x` to the variable `y`, your not creating a ***copy*** of `x`. Rather your creating a ***reference*** to the list `x`. This means that when either variable changes(`x` or `y`), they both change because they both point to the exact same list.

You need to *explicitly* tell Python to create a copy of `x`, to the variable `y`. That way, both variable will be independent of each other:

```
>>> x = [1, 2, 3]
>>> 
>>> def change(x):
...     y = x[:] # create a copy of x and not a reference
...     y.append(4) # change the copy
...     return y
... 
>>> x # before change
[1, 2, 3]
>>> change(x)
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> x # after change
[1, 2, 3]
>>>
```

Comment: Nice trick, Thank you very much :)

Comment: @FawzyHegab Much obliged Fawzy.